# jQuery asp button click function not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following does not work. Have a server submit button and trying to invoke the click action of the button on client side to so some validations. However, the function does not get invoked!

```html
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Next" ID="btnNext" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#<%= btnNext.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    alert("Success");
});
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.js file is loaded (I mean no 404 error)? The code looks fine..

Comment: Are you invoking the click on the server or with some other client-side javascript?

Comment: what does the html in the browser look like when you do view source? It could be that something isn't rendering as expected.

Comment: Please can you tell us what does your code to do with the header tag having a runat=server in it

Comment: no error, I had created a new web project to just test this piece and maybe that's how I still have the runat=server in head. but, does that affect my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason this particular "click" event runs when it is put inline in the aspx page itself. The moment I save it to the js file, it stops working. Keep in mind I have other controls on the page that have events in the same js file that works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling btnNext_Click, that code runs **server-side**. So the button's click event never gets triggered client-side.

If you want to trigger it client-side, you will need to use **client-side script**, eg:

```
if (<%= some_condition %>)
{
    $('#<%= btnNext.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

Comment: isn't that supposed to happen automatically like a radiobutton.change or a keypress event? why do we explicitly have to call this event when I have so many other events firing automatically on the same page with no issues?

Comment: @asa: ASP blurs the line between code that runs server-side and code that runs client-side, which can make it confusing. Usually a client-side click executes server-side code, not the other way around (like you're doing). I think you're going to have to click() your button manually using javascript (as above). If you find another way, let me know. ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Next" ID="btnNext" onClientClick="fnClickEvent();"/>
```

then in client code

```
    function fnClickEvent(){
        var valid = false;
        if (//validation code---){
             valid = true;
                } 
        if valid{ return true; }
        if notvalid { return false;} \\\ this prevents postback

         }
```

Comment: I just thought of this.. but, I am still bewildered as to why the event was not fired automatically on the button click like the radio.change that I have and working perfectly.

Comment: <asp:Button >  act differently then <input type="button" >  , i personally always use the second type , it is a common problem as you can see by googling "stop asp button from postback"

Comment: this also works, of course! just wanted to know why my code doesn't.